# Cloud Functions with Google Analytics trigger not always start

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-analytics-firebase

In Firebase, I have an event marked as conversion. This event triggers a Python 3.7 Cloud Function. Sometimes the function is triggered, sometimes not, even when the event was logged. It's not [error 10](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/errors) of Analytics error codes, as I will show in the next screenshots:

**Screenshot 1:** event in BigQuery at 09:03 UTC, with *firebase_conversion=1* and no *firebase_error* parameter:

[image]

**Screenshot 2:** Logs for the function, showing no logs for the event sent at 09:03 UTC (11:03 CEST), but there are logs for successive triggers:
[image]

Any idea what could be happening?

Comment: So all these calls that are logged are from the function that you expect to run and all of those calls are made by that specific event?

Comment: @ralemos The screenshot 2 only shows logs of the function that is triggered by this particular event. On the other hand, the function only is executed by this event trigger.

Comment: The trigger is automatic, so it does not make sense that the cloud function is being called intermitently. I would say that you should probably open a bug report on Google's [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187173&template=0) or seek their support to check what is happening on your case.